# Keep getting java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

I am having some trouble with an assignment for school. The comments show the pseudocode given by the instructor. For some reason, I keep getting this error:

```
java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared
```

Here is my code:

```
    // Declare and create a JPanel named panelMain. Use the horizontal BoxLayout layout manager.
    // Add some vertical glue to panelMain (using Box.createVerticalGlue()). Add panelLabel.
    // Add some more vertical glue. Add panelTextField. Add panelBottom. Add some more vertical
    // glue.

    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();


    panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    Box.createVerticalGlue();


    panelMain.add(panelLabel); //Error happens from here on
    panelMain.add(createVerticalGlue());
    panelMain.add(panelTextField);
    panelMain.add(panelBottom);
    panelMain.add(createVerticalGlue());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

You need the container that is getting the layout, panelMain, to be the same as the one within the BoxLayout constructor, not `getContentPane()`. So the correct code would be:

```
panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Resources:

- [BoxLayout API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html)
- [Relevant tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Comment: Thank you! Now however I am getting the same error slightly later in the program when I call setVisible(true);

Comment: @JonathanZier: then you've got a different problem there and need to debug it. This answer solves your current problem.

Comment: Yes, I had a different BoxLayout with the same problem. Thanks!